# WPF databinding equivalent in other technologies

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

In WPF a predominant concept is the databinding, which gave birth to the MVVM pattern.

I was wondering if such a concept (databinding) is also in other frameworks (Android, IOS), perhaps with a different name.

Comment: apple, google, oracle, or whatever wanna-be UI framework developers should all learn from WPF. HTML5 should have been XAML. I mean no, there's nothing in this world that compares to WPF. If it were we would all be really happier.

Comment: OSX has data binding (provided by Apple) and iOS is soon going to have it too: [AKA Beacon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88DkI8ZfEkg) - But you have a point, that's heavily inspired by WPF, Knockout & Co ;-)

While WPF is great, the Apple way also has some nice features (speed, animation power to mention two), I hope that Beacon can help to reduce the pain a bit... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other frameworks support their own versions of data binding or notification.  For example, iOS supports [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html), and Qt supports [QML Bindings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtbinding.html).  Unfortunately, there is nothing built-in with Android that provides this functionality.

Comment: Key-Value-Observing is great (also somewhat crazy and clumsy), but it's definitely not comparable in scope to WPF. It's a solid foundation to build upon, though.